# Can Spider-Man (Homecoming) sense people in another room?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-homecoming

I watched this *Spider-Man: Homecoming* trailer. In the trailer, Peter is sneaking to his room (in his Spider-Man suit) so Aunt May won't notice that he left his room.

But his friend is in his room the whole time while Peter is sneaking.

Why he didn't sense his friend's presence?

Here's the trailer:

Comment: probably because it was not a danger? as afar as I'm awared he cant sense people but only danger at least in the comics and other incarnations.

Comment: But exposing his identity is in danger, he should've known that.

Comment: bodily danger not social danger triggers his sense usually ;)

Comment: If societal/emotional danger triggered his spider-sense, he'd have avoided that whole dance scene in Spider-Man 3.

Comment: @Ramyle: his spider-sense understands the concept of a secret identity about as much as a spider would.

Comment: He's young and inexperienced, even if he does have spidey-senses, he was *very* focused on not alerting Aunt May. It was a simple oversight.

Comment: Aunt May doesn't trigger spider sense because she is viewed by Peter as not a threat. The same could be said about Ned.

Answer (score 4):

Spider-Man has the ability to cling to walls, superhuman strength, a spider-sense — that alerts him to danger — perfect balance and equilibrium, as well as superhuman speed and agility.

As mentioned by ***Thomas*** in the comment section, the presence of his friend did not trigger his spider-sense because his friend meant no bodily harm to him.

Comment: I feel like you could expand on the second paragraph by providing some canon info either from comics or other media..

Comment: Spidey wants to hide his identity and seems super alert to hide it from his aunt or anybody else present in the house. His spider sense should have alerted him of someone's presence in the room. As per your logic his spider sense will not alert him if one of his friend tries to snatch mask from his face

Comment: @HBhatia: “His spider sense should have alerted him of someone's presence in the room.” You seem pretty sure of how this entirely fictional sense works, despite the work of fiction that it appears in contradicting you.

Answer (score 0):

Spider man's Spidey Sense senses every type of Dangers.

As, his friend meant him no harm, spidey sense neglected it.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?

Comment: It doesn't require any source. Spidey Sense is for sensing dangers, everyone knows that

Comment: Haha, yeah most people know that, but maybe people new to Spider-Man may not know it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the MCU Spider-Man does not have a spider-sense.

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming* we more than once see Spider-Man blindsided with a punch, most clearly when exiting the school.

It is never stated one way or another in the movie, but is clear from the fights that he does not have it, or at least does not yet know how to use it.

Comment: [Kevin Feige re: spider-sense in the MCU](http://www.cbr.com/spider-man-homecoming-spider-sense-kevin-feige/): "I think he has it. And I think he has it with or without that suit. I think how we explore it in a cinematic sense will change,” Feige explained. “I mean, that was sort of a big showy part of previous versions and we thought that we’d make it more of an internal, sort of second nature thing for him.”

Comment: in civil war he is shown to preemptively notice the danger Ant-Man poses just before he retakes the shield from Spider-Man

Comment: “we more than once see Spider-Man blindsided with a punch, most clearly when exiting the school” — good shout on exiting the school during the dance, although I think it’s fair to say he was probably pretty distracted at that point.

Comment: In Civil War, he also raises his hand to catch the web fluid that Stark throws to him before Stark even begins to make the motion.

Comment: Isnt it so though that he has a sensory overload whenever he has no googles/no cosutme on? (he mentioned it in civil war)

Comment: We see that he does have it in the infinity war trailer